Getting the creator of an devops projects
Is it possible through the DevOps REST API to get the person who created the project? We are trying to delegate resposnibility to each project.

the information about the user who created a project is not directly accessible through the rest api. But you can get from audit log, please chek the details below, thanks.

In Azure DevOps, the information about the user who created a project is not directly accessible through the rest api.
But you can find the user who created the project from Aduit log:

You can export the audit log as csv format, and search Project {projectname} creation was started, it will show the user email.

Please note event get stored for 90 days in audit log, you can backup audit events to an external location to keep the data for longer than the 90-day period.

I wonder why in my case it shows the Azure DevOps Service as the creator?

You should check the creation started event

In case Azure DevOps audit logs are not available, take a look at the members of the [project-name]\Project Administrators group.
If I'm not mistaken the user that creates the project is automatically added to that group:

More users can be added to that group at any stage, of course. But this can limit your search to just a few users (administrator permissions shouldn't be given to everybody).
